# At what point are the effects of the Genocide route irreversible?

Tags: undertale

I want to do the Genocide route in the game (so I can do the Genocide only boss fights), but I also do not want to corrupt my save data with the effects of the Genocide route and get the 'soulless' True Pacifist ending. At what point can I still reset without affecting my save data?

Comment: Note that in addition to colorfusion's answer, there are several easy ways to edit your save data so the game acts as though you never completed the ending. So if you want to get through the full genocide route and still experience the other endings properly, you can do so.

Comment: I know that is possible but to me that feels like I'm breaking the message the game is trying to give you.

Comment: I'd argue it reinforces the message, considering the way you're trying to avoid it. But either way, it's all your choice. Just making sure you were aware.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think anything is breaking the message of the game at this point. You can modify the game's files and Toby knows it. Like the game implies, you are the one with all the power in the world.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reset at any point prior to the very last screen (after all bosses) where you are given a choice:

> The choice you see will be between "ERASE" and "DO NOT".

Comment: To clarify, until you select any of these one choices (which one you pick doesn't really matter), the effects of Genocide do not become permanent. You can always choose to reset before this point.

Comment: "No? You must be mistaken. SINCE WHEN WERE YOU THE ONE IN CONTROL?!"

Answer (score 2):

(SPOILERS, MUCH SPOILERS)

You can quit the Genocide Route when you want before Mettaton NEO by not exhausting the kill counters before his fight (you will continue on the Genocide Route and fight him even if stop killing before him, but then you will quit the route), after that, as New Home doesn't has monsters (only Flowey will be telling you about his life), you can't quit the route from this point. However, you can still reset before you meet Asgore and kill him and Flowey. Then you will meet Chara, when you can't close the game except if you use a Task Manager, so if you don't know how to open it, don't meet Asgore or you MUST give choose between ERASE or DON'T.

P.S: If you end up having to give the response to Chara, don't choose DO NOT. You will regret it. Also you can remove the Genocide Route effects by using Undertale Genocide Remover, Flowey's Time Machine or erase it manually (If you're on Steam, it will mess you up).